# A verb which describes the action of putting your leg over somebody else's body when sleeping

Tags: word-request

My girlfriend and I both like putting our legs over each other's when sleeping. We've been trying to find the English verb for this for a while. Does English have such a word?

Comment: It's not specific to legs, but I would use "to intertwine" say "I like waking up intertwined with you." This could refer to any form of being very close and having limbs crossed or wrapped around one another.

Comment: Normally, only the person who gets to put their leg over the other's body feels comfortable. That's why the other might say, "Stop ____-ing me!" I suppose we can't say, "Stop intertwining with me!" So, what should we say in this situation?

Comment: [straddle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/straddle) is perhaps more colloquial than intertwine or bestride. In Julius Caesar, Cassius famously says of Caesar, "Why, man, he doth bestride the narrow world | Like a Colossus."

Comment: Ahh, that context helps! I agree with @OldBrixtonian that the word "straddle" is the closest description of the physical act. I think that native speakers are more likely though in this case to refer to the effect of the leg. I've said to my partner "Stop smothering me!" if I feel like I am pinned down and can't move or can't breathe. Alternatively, "Stop squishing me!" if their body is too heavy on mine.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Straddles means "to sit or stand with one of your legs on either side of somebody/something". When I hear "straddle", I often think about the riding-a-horse position. But here both are lying next to each other, there's just one leg, not the whole body, being put over the other.

Comment: The question says you both like it. Your comment says it's smothering and squishing. Between partners, the wordsmithing is bookish if you like it, and scolding  if you dislike it. In NY, we would have said I'll let you know when I want to be humped. Actually.

Comment: Wow, humping means a lot differently in my dictionary lol. By the way, in my question, I meant we both liked it when we were the one who got to put the leg over.

Comment: @Ken Adams: When you hear "straddle" you understand it to mean "astride"? Any idea why? Did you check my link to a dictionary? I would choose from, "Her leg straddling mine," "Her legs straddling mine. Or if you have to get specific, "Her leg(s) straddling one/both of mine".

Comment: I think I'm under that impressiom because I've once read this example in the OALD: _He swung his leg over the motorcycle, straddling it easily._

Comment: In informal British English 'getting your leg over' means something rather more than the action described.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian- I would understand _straddle_ to mean _astride_ too. Used in this context, it would sound to me as though the person doing it was trying to initiate sex, not just cuddling up.

Comment: @KateBunting - that's how I usually interpret it!

Comment: My girlfriend and I both like putting our legs over each other's when sleeping.=Nope. Either the legs are intertwined, OR one is draping his or her leg over the other. straddle is not right here because when you straddle, you are on top of the person (ahem).

Comment: Is this pure imagination, or are you looking for a translation from another language, please?

If you're looking for a translation, which language is that from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe there is a specific single word in English that exclusively describes draping a leg over someone in the same way that "hug" specifically refers to putting arms around someone.

'Cuddling' tends to mean more than just a hug, especially seated or in bed where it is possible to become more intertwined with another person. But again, it doesn't specifically describe what you mean.

There are some names for certain positions of closeness, for example '*spooning*' refers to two people lying side by side, facing the same direction, but this can also describe a sexual position as well as a cuddling technique! Again, perhaps not what you want.

If you're looking for a verb of the actual action of placing the leg over someone rather than a noun for the position you end up in, I would use the language from my first paragraph - "*draping* a leg over".

> Drape: to put something loosely over something:

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 100k rep.

Answer (score 1):

The comments suggested *straddle* (although this primarily means sitting on top of something with your legs around it). *Cover* could also work.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with these suggestions - '*straddle*' very specifically means "sit or stand with one leg on either side of", so it couldn't be used for a lying position. And '*cover*' means to put something over or around so as to conceal i; in other words, *completely* cover. A leg cannot completely cover a whole torso.